# Setting Default Colors from android Programmatically

Tags: android, android-studio, colors

I am having a problem, i know how to set colors programmatically using the following method

For Example:

```
imageButton.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorAccent));
```

This works just fine what about if i don't want to set the colors from colors.xml for example
the following colors in XML

```
android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
```

I want to set the colors above programmatically i don't want to use the colors in colors.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

`getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_orange_dark)`

Here's the full code:

`imageButton.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_orange_dark));`

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask for clarifications...